# How can I translate a Word page into LaTeX?

Tags: text

I would like to learn to make a Word document to LaTeX. In particularly, I found on the internet an essay template in Word format in https://www.jyu.fi/edupsy/fi/opiskelu/opiskeluohjeet/pikaohjeet/esseen-tyylipohja_paivitetty-22-9-2021.docx and I would like to translate it to LaTeX. Currently I am writing the cover page. My effort goes as below. But what is my mistake as the Caption and Author name goes so below? Is there wiser way to do it than my current code?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    top=2.5cm,%
    bottom=2.5cm,%
    headheight=33pt,%
]{geometry}%
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\footheight}{17.99445pt}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setmainfont{Book Antiqua}
  \begin{center}
{\fontsize{16pt}{48pt}\selectfont \textbf{Caption}} 

{\fontsize{14pt}{48pt}\selectfont Author name} 
\end{center}
\newpage\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please insert an image of the cover page you want. External links can become invalid or inaccessible, and the question could lose any value to future visitors.

Comment: I think there might be copyright issues is I insert an image.

Comment: All the code sample does is select a font and print the word "Caption' large, bold, and centered, and below it in a smaller font, the words "Author name". Try cutting out everything between `\documentclass{}` and `\begin{document}`, then using this for the document: `{\Large\textbf{Caption}}

{\large Author name}` (with a blank line between the two lines in case that doesn't show in this comment).